# Is $n=1$ (degrees of freedom) for monatomic?

Tags: thermodynamics, degrees-of-freedom

In $PV=nRT$, $n$ is degrees of freedom. While in $PV=Nk_BT$, N is number of moles in a molecule. So value of $n$ is $3$, $5$ and $6$ for monatomic, diatomic and polyatomic respectively. But in [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-ek0HYLT6E), he wrote that $n=1$ for monatomic. Isn't that a wrong assumption?

Comment: You have several errors in your post. N is the number of molecules,  n is the number of moles. "The number of moles in a molecule" is nonsense.

Comment: You've completely misunderstood the terms "n" and "N".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ideal gas law
$$PV=nRT$$
$n$ is not the degrees of freedom.
Instead $n$ is the number of molecules (measured in mol).
You can see this also from the unit of the [gas constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant)
$$R=8.314 \text{ m}^3\text{ Pa}\text{ K}^{-1}\text{ mol}^{-1}$$

Comment: Oops, $f$ is degrees of freedom.